# Construction of a class in java

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I should carry out this exercise in the creation of a class, I uploaded this is the professor's solution, in sum and product methods can not quite figure out what place and why use "A".

```
class Vettore {
    private int[] V = new int[6];
    public Vettore(int[] X) {
        if (X.length != 6)
            throw new BadDataException();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            if (X[i] < 0)
                throw new BadDataException();
            else
                V[i] = X[i];
    }
    public Vettore() {}
    public Vettore somma(Vettore X) {
        int[] A = new int[6];
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            A[i] = V[i] + X.V[i];
        return new Vettore(A);
    }
    public Vettore prodotto(Vettore X) {
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            k += V[i] * X.V[i];
        return k;
    }
    public int get(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i > 5)
            throw new BadDataException();
        return V[i];
    }
    public String toString() {
        String t = "( ";
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            t += V[i] + (i == 5 ? " " : ", ");
        return t + ")";
    }
    public boolean equals(Vettore X) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            if (V[i] != X.V[i])
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: your `prodotto` method returns an `int` while its signature specifies `Vettore` return type! You should probably elaborate on what is it that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I see it, and assuming `somma` means `sum` and `prodotto` means `product`, The `A` is needed because you have to store the sum values of the `V` and `X.V` arrays **for every index**. If you didn't use another `array` for this, you wouldn't be able to achive adding the appropriate indexes in `somma` for example. This method stands for - as I see it - `Adding the two arrays' appropriate elements`.

**EDIT:** another thing. Are you sure that the return types match variables to return? I elaborated the use of `somma` but didn't pay attention that `prodotto` has a wrong return type, just as it was said in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

1. You might want to correct the `prodotto` method definition as -

   ```
   public Vettore prodotto(Vettore X) {
       int[] K = new int[6]; //  deault values are 0
       for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
           K[i] += V[i] * X.V[i];
       return new Vettore(K);
   }
   ```

This would evaluate the product of the array field `V` for two instances of class `Vettore` namingly `X` the input param and the current instance that you would call the method from.

2. `return new Vettore(K);` creates a new instance of `Vettore` class with K as arrays field, while executing the constructor logic in place as follows -

   ```
   public SumAndProductExercise(int[] X) {
       if (X.length != 6) { // length of the array is 6 or not
           throw new BadDataException();
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
           if (X[i] < 0) { // all the elements of array are >=0 or not
               throw new BadDataException();
           } else {
               V[i] = X[i]; // the field on the new instance
           }
       }
   }
   ```